# Javascript object structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form collecting employee production data, the following is the code:

```
$(document).on('click','input#Apply.btn.btn-success',function(e){

    var TableData;
    TableData = storeTblValues();  
    var TableData1 = [];

    $.each(TableData,function(index,value){

        if(value.quantity && value.quantity >0 && value.quantity < 65535){    
            TableData1[index]={

               "employee_id" : value.employee_id
            ,  "operation_id" : value.operation_id
            ,  "quantity" : value.quantity       
            }

        }   
            }); 
    // retrieving employee_id to fetch date data from date input          
    $.each(TableData1,function(index,value){         
         employee_idj = value.employee_id;
        }); 

    $('#cboxClose').click(); 
    var datee = dateConvToMySqlDate($('input#dateOfProduction_'+employee_idj+'.dateOfProduction_.hasDatepicker').val());
    if(!datee){alert(dateMessager);e.preventPropagation();return false;}
    var noOfRecords = TableData1.length;

    for(i=0;i<noOfRecords;i++)
    {TableData1[i]['production_date'] = datee;}

    var TableData1 = $.toJSON(TableData1); 
    alert(JSON.stringify(TableData1));
    var qurl = '<?php echo base_url();?>production_entry/submitData';
    $.ajax({
    url: qurl,
    type: "POST",    
    data:"pTableData=" + TableData1,           
    success: function(data){

            var data = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(data.status == 'error')
            {
            alert(data.errorMessage);   
            }else{ 
            alert(noOfRecords+' records sent and '+' '+data.successMessage);

              $('#tr_'+employee_idj).fadeOut();
            }
          }
    });

    function storeTblValues()
    {    

        var TableData = new Array();

        $('#searchOperationTable tr').each(function(row, tr){

         var x = parseInt($(tr).find("input.quantity").val());   

            if(x){
            TableData[row]={

               "employee_id" : parseInt($(tr).find("input.hiddenemployeeId").val())
            ,  "operation_id" : parseInt($(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text())
            ,  "quantity" : parseInt($(tr).find("input.quantity").val())       
            }
        }
            }); 
            TableData.shift();
            return TableData;
    }

});
```

When someone enter a quantity value equal to 0 mistakenly, then the TableData1 object becomes

```
[ null,{"employee_id" : 3816,"operation_id":3,"quantity":10}]
```

and the script stops working. I want to eliminate this null. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your check `if(x)` is false when a 0 is entered, so `TableData[row]` will not be set for that entry. Instead, set your TableData using `array.push`:

```
     if(x){
        TableData.push({
           "employee_id" : parseInt($(tr).find("input.hiddenemployeeId").val())
        ,  "operation_id" : parseInt($(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text())
        ,  "quantity" : parseInt($(tr).find("input.quantity").val())       
        })
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the index values of the array, then you can use `push(value)` instead of `array[index]=value`.
like in my example:

```
TableData.push({
    "employee_id" : parseInt($(tr).find("input.hiddenemployeeId").val()),
    "operation_id" : parseInt($(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()),
    "quantity" : parseInt($(tr).find("input.quantity").val())       
});`
```